# Proof verification for Identity matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

So I have the following question:

Analyze the following 'Claim' (which may or may not be true) and the corresponding 'Proof', by writing 'TRUE' or 'FALSE' (together with the reason) for each step. [Note: $I_n$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix.]

Claim: Let $A$ be any $n \times n$ matrix satisfying $A^2=I_n$. Then either $A=I_n$ or $A=-I_n$.

'Proof'.

**Step 1:** $A$ satisfies $A^2-I_n = 0$ (True or False)

True.

*My reasoning: Clearly, this is true. $A^2=I_n$ is not always true, but because it is true, I should have no problem moving the Identity matrix the the LHS.*

**Step 2:** So $(A+I_n)(A-I_n)=0$ (True or false)

True.

*My reasoning: Because $I_n$ is the identity matrix, there should be no issues with factoring just like normal algebra.*

**Step 3:** $A+I_n=0$ or $A-I_n=0$

*I'm not sure about this part. I'm very tempted to say this is fine but I am not sure how I can justify this, if I even can.*

Therefore $A=-I_n$ or $A=I_n$. (End of 'Proof'.)

Is what I am doing right so far or am I messing up somewhere?

Comment: What's the square of $A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- Rather than saying that moving the identiy to the LHS, it is due to we add $-I$ to both sides.
- We have $A^2-I=(A-I)(A+I)$, we just have to expand the right hand side to verify that.
- In matrices, $AB=0$ doesn't imply that $A=0$ or $B=0$. For example $$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -2\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$
- In particular,

$$\left(\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\right)\left(\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\right)= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

that is we cant' conclude that $(A+I)(A-I)=0$ implies $A+I=0$ or $A-I=0$ as well.

Comment: Aha. I knew something looked fishy with that last part. Thanks!

Comment: When expanding the right hand side, be sure to respect the non-commutativity of matrix multiplication.  $$(A+I)(A-I) = (A+I)A - (A+I)I$$ $$\qquad = A^2 + IA - AI -I^2 = A^2 - I^2.$$  Although the difference in this particular problem is negligible, it is not generally so.

Comment: In the third point it should be "that $A=0$ *or* $B=0$".

Comment: thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I would like this answer better if $A$ and $B$ were of the form $A\pm I$ so that it matches OP's proof.  Using the other answer, you could take $A=diag(2,0)$ and $B=diag(0,-2)$, so that they are $diag(1,-1)\pm I$.

Comment: thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 9):

Consider any diagonal matrix with diagonal elements $\pm 1$. Show that$A^{2}=I_n$. you get $2^{n}$ matrices whose square is $I_n$.

Answer (score 2):

Furthermore if you want a concrete example of a matrix whose square is the identity but not itself a simple matrix consider for example this one:

$$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2} & \frac{3}{4} \\ 1 & -\frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}$$

These matrices are called [involuntory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involutory_matrix)